# Kotlin flow doesn't appear to be collecting from Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, apollo-kotlin

I've created a class to wrap around Kotlin GraphQL queries:

```kotlin
class GraphQuery<DataType : Query.Data>(
    private val api: Api,
    private val queryFactory: suspend () -> Query<DataType>,
) {

    private val control: MutableStateFlow<GraphQueryState<DataType>> = MutableStateFlow(GraphQueryState.NotStarted())

    public val flow = control
        .onStart { emit(GraphQueryState.Loading()) }
        .flatMapConcat {

            api.client
                .query(queryFactory())
                .fetchPolicy(FetchPolicy.NetworkOnly)
                .watch()
                .map { response ->
                    when (response.hasErrors()) {
                        true -> GraphQueryState.Error(response.errors!!)
                        else -> GraphQueryState.Ready(response.data!!)
                    }
                }
        }

    public fun update(data: DataType) {
        control.value = GraphQueryState.Updating(data)
    }

    public fun refresh() {
        control.value = GraphQueryState.Loading()
    }
}
```

The general intent is to reduce boilerplate code and give my application a consistent approach to retrieving data.

I consume an instance of this class via my `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class EditWebPaymentSettingsViewModel @Inject constructor (
    appSettings: DataStore<Settings>,
    api: Api,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val settingsQuery = GraphQuery(api) {

        val settings = appSettings.data.last()

        SettingsForAdminQuery(
            UUID.fromString(settings.currentOrganizationId),
            SupportedSettingPurpose.WebPayment.value,
        )
    }

    public val settings = settingsQuery.flow
}
```

Which is then consumed by a `Composable` in my application:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EditWebPaymentSettingsScreen(
    done: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: EditWebPaymentSettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val webPaymentSettings by viewModel.settings.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(GraphQueryState.NotStarted())

    when (webPaymentSettings) {

        is GraphQueryState.Loading,
        is GraphQueryState.NotStarted -> Loading()

        is GraphQueryState.Ready,
        is GraphQueryState.Updating -> TODO()

        is GraphQueryState.Error -> TODO()
    }
}
```

My problem is, I never get to any of the `TODO()` blocks.  My `webPaymentSettings` remains the initial `NotStarted` value indefinitely and my query never runs.

Is there any easy way to tell why my query never runs?  My utility class does a `flatMapConcat` which makes me think that the query should be issued after the very first value. I'm under the impression it's a *hot* flow because I'm using a `MutableStateFlow`, but maybe there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your flow chain, we have:

```kotlin
control
        .onStart { emit(GraphQueryState.Loading()) }
```

which is a flow that emits first `Loading`, then `NotStarted` (probably not what you intended), then

```kotlin
.flatMapConcat {
  <Apollo Kotlin watch>
}
```

which takes emissions and replaces them with the Apollo Kotlin call.

(Noteworthy: `watch()` never completes.)

So you should never get `Loading` nor `NotStarted`, but only `Ready` or `Error`.

But you never get `Ready` nor `Error` - could it be that `appSettings.data.last()` blocks?